# AWS API Gateway - Removed lambda function references when update the documentation

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, lambda, swagger, aws-api-gateway

I am trying to update my documentation in AWS API Gateway using a swagger import.

I am using the option **Merge** however every time i do it, it removes all the references from the endpoint to the lambda functions that I have already set.

So I have to go through a set them again.

So I don't have to go back through all the endpoints and reset the Lambda functions before deploying it.

Is there a way that I can make sure the Lambda functions stay set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way for a swagger import to keep the references.

A better way to do it would be to just use API Gateway to create your API.
And then export the swagger when you want to document your API.
This way you won't have that issue.

I hope this helps you.